# Cacti CDEF function to plot several interfaces on one traffic graph

Tags: interface, cacti

The final graph I want to plot is similar to below graph.
[image: Several data source "stacking" in one graph]

CDEF function to plot this graph manually (through command line) is like:

```
DEF:t1=$RRD_PATH:telnet:AVERAGE \ 
DEF:t2=$RRD_PATH:smtp:AVERAGE \ 
DEF:t3=$RRD_PATH:domain:AVERAGE \ 
DEF:t4=$RRD_PATH:http:AVERAGE \ 
DEF:t5=$RRD_PATH:total:AVERAGE \ 
CDEF:v1=t1,t2,t3,t4,+,+,+ \ 
CDEF:v2=t1,t2,t3,+,+ \ 
CDEF:v3=t1,t2,+ \ 
CDEF:v4=t1 \ 
CDEF:v5=t5,1024,/ \ 
AREA:v1#339966:"HTTP" \ 
AREA:v3#FF0000:"SMTP" \ 
AREA:v4#0000ff:"TELNET" \ 
LINE2:v5#000000:"Total(Kb)" \
```

However, I want to define CDEF functions **on Cacti Console/interface**, to realize this "stacking effect". For example, inbound traffic of Fa0/1-24 is t1-t24, data presented on the graph should be: t1, t1+t2, t1+t2+t3, ... etc.

Any idea on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cacti naturally supports this function. Choose **STACK** as the *Graph Item Type*, starting from the second data source. 
[image]

Then the graph of following data sources will stack on the previous graphs. Final output I got is like below graph:

[image]